# How to recursively find the number of files in each directory across all directories in a system without root access?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

This doesn't seem to work

```
find . -type f | uniq -w 8 -c|sort -n > answer3.txt && sort -t',' -nk1 answer3.txt | awk 'NR==999;END{print}
```

It gives a permission denied and I don't have the means to override permissions.

Comment: When you neither have the permission to read some directories nor to change their permissions, then you cannot search that directories. There is just no way. All you could do is to tell `find` to ignore directories you cannot access.

Comment: You can ignore errors by appending `2> /dev/null`, but if you don't have permissions then you can't access all directories.  Security is there for a reason.

Comment: Alright! Thank you!But is there any way to obtain only the number of files present in directories to which i have no access?

Comment: *»is there any way to obtain only the number of files present in directories to which i have no access?«*. No. If you don't have access to a directory, then there is no way for you to get any information about that directorie's content.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to read file in directories, where You do not have access. 
I propose read this wiki page, especially "Examples" chapter. [wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes)

Comment: Thanks!I shall go through the page.